# C++ shifting bits

Tags: c++, bit-shift, 64-bit

I am new to shifting bits, but I am trying to debug the following snippet:

```
if (!(strcmp(arr[i].GetValType(), "f64")))
 {
        dem_content_buff[BytFldPos] = tmp_data;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 1] =  tmp_data >> 8;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 2] = tmp_data >> 16;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 3] = tmp_data >> 24;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 4] = tmp_data >> 32;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 5] = tmp_data >> 40;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 6] = tmp_data >> 48;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 7] = tmp_data >> 56;
        }
```

I am getting a warning saying the lines with "32" to "56" have a shift count that is too large.  The "f64" in the predicate just means that the data should be 64bit data.

How should this be done?

edit:

I should have put more of the code in.

```
tmp_data = simulated_data[index_data];

if (!(strcmp(dems[i].GetValType(), "s32")))
```

{
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos] = tmp_data;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 1] = tmp_data >> 8;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 2] = tmp_data >> 16;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 3] = tmp_data >> 24;
 }

if (!(strcmp(dems[i].GetValType(), "f64")))
 {
        dem_content_buff[BytFldPos] = tmp_data;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 1] = tmp_data >> 8;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 2] = tmp_data >> 16;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 3] = tmp_data >> 24;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 4] = tmp_data >> 32;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 5] = tmp_data >> 40;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 6] = tmp_data >> 48;
     dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 7] = tmp_data >> 56;
 }

So, `dem_content_buff` right now only holds ints.  Can I not use this array for the 64 bit data either?

Comment: What type is `tmp_data`?  You probably will want that to be a 64-bit type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use 64bit long type for the tmp_data as was suggested before the unsinged long long should work, but check your compiler and architecture documentation.

The code should look like this.  Also, make sure that your demp_content_buff is declared as unsigned char * or unsigned char [].

Then change your code to:

```
if (!(strcmp(arr[i].GetValType(), "f64")))
    {
        dem_content_buff[BytFldPos] =  ( tmp_data & 0xff );
        dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 1] =  (tmp_data >> 8 ) & 0xff ;
        dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 2] =  (tmp_data >> 16) & 0xff ;
        dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 3] =  (tmp_data >> 24) & 0xff;
        dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 4] =  (tmp_data >> 32) & 0xff;
        dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 5] =  (tmp_data >> 40) & 0xff;
        dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 6] =  (tmp_data >> 48) & 0xff;
        dem_content_buff[BytFldPos + 7] =  (tmp_data >> 56) & 0xff;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the type of `tmp_data`?

My guess is that `tmp_data` is only 32-bits, hence the error. It will need to be a 64-bit unsigned int, which is can be achieved using the non-standard (but well-supported) `unsigned long long` data type.

Comment: This code doesn't put any restrictions on the type of `dem_content_buff`.  In fact, it looks like it's supposed to be an 8-bit type.

Answer (score 1):

For the shift operator to work shifting more than 32 bits, `tmp_data` will need to be a 64-bit type - as several other answers indicated.

However, you would also want `simulated_data` to be an array of some 64-bit type otherwise `tmp_data` will always be zero (or a sign-extended set of `1` bits)  in the most significant bits when you assign its original value:

```
tmp_data = simulated_data[index_data];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio, make sure that you define tmp_data as:

```
__int64 tmp_data;              // Visual studio version
```

instead of

```
unsigned long long tmp_data;   // GCC version
```